# why is github showing all my previous commits in every new repository i push to?

Tags: git, github, repository

am not a github pro thats why i need clarity. Each time i create a new repo on github and push new cntent to it i discover that all the previous commits on other repositories are also added in my new repo. making all my repos similar to each other except for one or two folders which is not looking good.
when i add new folders in my repo folder on my local machine, that is my laptop, i then navigate to that repo folder and then to the new folder i added and run the git add  and run git status, i see nothing has been added for staging. However when i go back to the repo folder and run git add . it adds all the content of the new folder i just added which sounds good but when i make a commit and push, it adds all previous commits to that new repo.

Comment: Did you `git init` within the newly created folder?

Comment: no i didn't. so when i add a new folder to my main folder (repo) on my local machine i should run a git init right? so after i run that command, what next?

Comment: It looks like your ran `git init` in a higher directory (your home directory perhaps ?) and you are versionning all your projects together in the same, single git repository.

Comment: Creating a fresh new repo is as easy as `git init` in the correct directory. This will however not keep the history of that project (if there is any). Do you need to separate the history of several of your existing projects ?

Comment: yes i want to do that

Answer (score 1):

This is a Git issue rather than a GitHub one, and it stems from not being correctly taught how to use Git in the first place.  (Unless you're entirely self-taught, this is not your fault, or not entirely your fault.  If you are learning on your own, be aware that a whole lot of Git tutorials are anywhere from not-very-good to downright bad.)

Git is mainly about *commits*.  A Git *repository* is, first and foremost, a collection of *commits*.  As such, you need to know what a commit is and does for you, how you make a *new* repository, how Git *finds* a repository, and, well, a great deal more: Git can get pretty darn complicated.  But let's start simple:

- A Git *repository* consists primarily of a pair of databases.  One database holds *commits and other supporting objects*, and the other database holds *names* such as branch and tag names.  We'll get to the reason for the second database in a moment.
- A *useful* Git repository—the kind you use on your laptop, for instance—also comes with a *working tree*, which we'll get to as well.  (The kind of Git repository found on servers such as GitHub or Bitbucket is a "bare" repository, which simply omits the working tree so that nobody can work on it: this is useful because it allows `git push` to work to send *to* that repository.  But that's not what you want on your laptop.  You want a normal, non-bare, repository.)

Git puts these databases, plus a bunch of auxiliary files that Git needs to operate, into a hidden directory or folder (these terms are now interchangeable, so use whichever one you prefer).  This hidden folder is named `.git` and, in most normal repositories, this hidden `.git` folder is found at the *top level of the working tree*.  This is in fact how Git figures out what your working tree is.

Suppose, for instance, that your home directory (folder) is `/home/bob` (Linux) or `/Users/bob` (macOS) or whatever.  Inside this folder, you probably have many sub-folders.  I like to organize my sources within a `src` directory for instance, and some subsystems like Go require (or used to require) particular paths as well.  So you might:

```
cd /home/bob/src/fun
mkdir experiment1
cd experiment1
```

to create a new for-fun experimental source project.  Within this you'll have `frontend/` and `backend/` sub-folders, perhaps, for a web server toy of some sort, or whatever it is that you plan to experiment with.  If you'd like to have *one Git repository* to contain all of these, you would now run:

```
git init
```

to create a *new, totally-empty repository* (two empty databases) where you are now.  This will create `/home/bob/src/fun/experiment1/.git/` and fill in a bunch of files to hold the various databases and other stuff.

You're now free to create sub-folders and `cd` into them.  Let's say you make `py` as a Python-code sub-folder here, and `cd` into it.  When you run Git commands, they'll look for the hidden `.git` here, and *not find it*.  So they'll climb up one path element, from `/home/bob/src/fun/experiment1/py/` to `/home/bob/src/fun/experiment1/` and look for the hidden `.git` here.  **This time they find it** so your *working tree* is rooted at `/home/bob/src/fun/experiment1/`.  The *repository proper* is in `/home/bob/src/fun/experiment1/.git`.

#### The first commit is weird and a bit special

At this point, you still have *no commits at all*.  A repository with no *commits* cannot have any *branches*.  Fortunately Git doesn't need a branch to operate, but you really want to have a branch name, so Git sets one up anyway, even though you don't have it.  If you run `git status` at this point, Git will tell you that you are `on branch master` or `on branch main` or whatever, even though that branch doesn't exist!

You can change the name of the branch that doesn't exist, but that you're on, with `git init --initial-branch=main` for instance, but since it doesn't actually exist anyway, it's not really very important.  Still, you'll want to make a first commit pretty quickly, so that the branch name starts existing.  I like to create an initial `README` file or similar and commit that:

```
$ echo playing around with the foo language > README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
```

(the initial commit message here is dull and template-y as the initial commit itself is dull and template-y).

Having this initial commit, so that you have a branch whose name you can now *change*, is nice.  But if you intend to use GitHub or some other web hosting site, you can choose to skip *all of this work* by using their web site to *create a repository with one initial commit **in** it*, using the clicky web buttons or whatever.  If you do *that* you can then `git clone` the initial single-commit repository to your laptop, skipping the whole `git init`-and-create-one-commit steps on your side.  The `git clone` operation will set up the *remote* named `origin` for you and copy the one initial commit, putting all of these into a *new repository* made by making an empty directory—that same `mkdir experiment1` above—and then running `git init` in it *for you*.

**It is your choice as to whether to make your own initial commit, or let GitHub or whatever make one for you, but pick one or the other: don't do both!**  If you do both, you'll get *two* initial, slightly-weird-and-special commits, and this makes trouble later.  (It's not insurmountable but it's an annoyance that you can skip if you just pick one.)

If you do run `git init` yourself and make your own initial commit, remember to create your GitHub-or-whatever repository with *no* initial commit, and do the `git remote add origin` step yourself.

#### Commits

This is what you need to know about commits:

- Each commit is *numbered*.  The numbers are *huge*, weird and random-looking as they're expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), and they are *unique*.  Git generates them on its own (using a cryptographic checksum technique and the huge range of possible numbers to try to guarantee this uniqueness; Git doesn't work unless the numbers *are* unique).
- Each commit stores two things: a *full snapshot of every file* and some *metadata*.
- All this stuff is read-only.  (That's required to make the numbering scheme work.)

There's more to learn, but we'll stop here for now.

The full snapshot is stored (indirectly) via other non-commit objects, in that big objects database, along with the commit.  The files in this full snapshot have names such as `py/main.py`, complete with embedded (forward) slashes (even on Windows): there are no *folders*, just these file names.  Git knows about folders and will make them as needed on your computer so as to be able to *extract* the committed files later, but Git doesn't *store* the folders (which is why [you can't store an empty directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/1256452)).  The files are kept in a special, compressed and (importantly) *de-duplicated* format, so that the Git repository doesn't become grossly fat even though every commit stores every file.

The *metadata* in a commit holds information about the commit itself.  This includes your name and email address, for instance, and some date-and-time-stamps and so on.  Crucially for Git's own operation, each commit's metadata holds the *raw hash ID* of some earlier commit(s).  Most commits hold exactly one such hash ID: these are *ordinary* commits.  Some commits are *merge commit* and hold two (or, technically, two-or-more) previous-commit hash IDs.

At least one commit in any non-empty repository is special: its list of previous commit hash IDs is *empty*.  That's the weird, slightly-special one we made as a sort of template initial commit, just to get it out of the way.  That commit will ultimately be on *every branch*, as we'll see.  Git calls this commit a (or the) *root* commit.

Git stores all of this stuff—the commit object, and all of its supporting objects—in the big all-objects database that makes up the bulk of almost all repositories.<sup>1</sup>  This all-objects database is a simple [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database) with the hash IDs as the keys, so Git *needs* the hash ID to find a commit quickly.  Hence we're going to have to memorize some hash IDs, although very soon, we'll see how we can avoid that.

Because each commit (except a root commit) holds at least one *previous* commit hash ID—and most hold *exactly* one—we only need to memorize the *latest* commit hash ID.  Suppose we have a repository that has about eight commits in it.  We'll assign uppercase letters to stand in for hash IDs, such as `H` for Hash, and draw one such commit like this:

```
            <-H
```

That little arrow sticking out of the commit here, in this drawing, represents the stored hash ID in the metadata for commit `H`.  That is, given the hash ID for `H`, Git can fish commit `H` out of the objects database (and quickly) and find inside it the hash ID of the *previous* commit.  Let's call that commit `G` and draw it in:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Commit `G`, like `H`, is an ordinary commit, so it stores the hash ID of a still-earlier commit.  Git can fish out this hash ID and use it to find that still-earlier commit:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

This goes on forever, or rather, until Git hits the very first commit ever: commit `A`, presumably.  That's our *root commit* and it allows Git to stop working backwards.

**Note that Git works backwards, starting from the *last* commit.**  We need to somehow memorize the hash ID of the *latest* commit.  Hash IDs are ugly and impossible for humans to memorize, so what can we do here?

---

<sup>1</sup>If you make a repository and put just a few tiny commits in it, then create millions of branch and tag names, the bulk of the repository consists of the names, instead of the commits.  That's not at all normal but is the reason to weasel-word the statement for which this is a footnote.

---

#### Branch names memorize hash IDs for us

Instead of *us* memorizing the latest commit hash ID, why don't we store it in a file, or maybe even a simple key-value database?  That's a great idea: let's have a database of *names*, like branch and tag names, and have each *name* store a hash ID.

If we **define** a *branch* name as "this thing holds the hash ID of the latest commit", and draw that in, we get:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

(assuming we're using branch name `main`).  The *name* `main` holds `H`'s hash ID, so `H` *points to* `H`, the way `H` points back to `G`, and `G` points back to `F` and so on.  We get a little lazy about drawing the arrows from commit-to-commit, because they literally *can't* change.  They're stored *in the commit* (in the metadata) and the commit is *entirely read only*.  So if `H` points to `G`, this means `H` points to `G` *forever*.  The arrows don't point forwards because we didn't know what `H`'s hash ID would be when we made `G`.  (The hash ID depends on *everything*, including those exact time stamps, and we don't know, when we make `G`, the *time* at which we'll make `H` in the future.  We also don't know what `G`'s ID will be, and the hash of `H` includes hashing the hash ID of `G` once it goes into `H`!)

If we have *more than one branch name*, each such name *points to* some commit.  So if we want to make a new name now, such as `develop` or `feature` or whatever, we pick some existing commit—probably `H` since it's the latest—and make the name point there:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop, main
```

Now we need a way to remember which *name* we're using.  We'll have Git attach the special name `HEAD` to exactly one branch name, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop, main (HEAD)
```

This says that we are *using commit `H`* and we are doing so *through the name `main`*.

If we now run `git switch develop` or `git checkout develop`, we get this:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), main
```

We are still *using commit `H`* but now we are doing so *through the name `develop`*.

Why does this matter?  The answer has to do with what happens when we make a *new* commit.  For now, note that *every commit* is on *both branches*.  As soon as we made a new branch name, commit `H` was on *two* branches.  Before, commit `H` was on *one* branch.  **Nothing changed in commit `H` at all** (because nothing can) but the *set of branches that contain it* changed anyway!

This is a clue: branch names aren't actually very important—except in one way: they let us, and Git, *find* some commit.  Git needs the hash ID, and the branch name holds the hash ID.  And that's pretty much it, and also explains the next bit.

#### Making a new commit updates the current branch name

Let's say we have this now:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), main
```

and we make a *new commit* in the usual way (without worrying about what that "way" is).  The new commit will be an ordinary commit, so it will have a parent.  The parent of the new commit will be whatever commit we're using when we *make* the new commit.  We're using `H`, so the parent of the new commit will be `H`: our new commit will point backwards to `H`.

The new commit will get a new, unpredictable (random-looking but not actually random) hash ID that is unique—no other Git repository anywhere in the universe can be using that ID before we get it, and none can use it after we get it<sup>2</sup>—but we'll just call it `I`, and draw it in:

```
....--G--H   <-- main
          \
           I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Having obtained `I`'s hash ID (by writing commit `I` into the database), Git stuffs that new hash ID into the *current branch name*, so now `develop`, to which `HEAD` is attached, points to `I`.

Commit `H` remains on `develop` and on `main`, but new commit `I` is—*currently* anyway—only on branch `develop`.  Only the name `develop` finds `I`.  There are two ways to find `H`: using `main`, or using `develop` and then working backwards one hop.

---

<sup>2</sup>This is mathematically impossible to keep up forever (see the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) and Git is doomed to fail someday.  The size of the hash space puts that day far enough into the future that we can hope that we're all dead, and perhaps the entire universe has ended in an entropic heat death, before it occurs.

---

#### Your working tree, and Git's index / staging-area

I'm only going to touch on this lightly to keep things short (well, short*er* anyway), but:

- *Checking out* a commit, with `git switch` or `git checkout`, tells Git *remove from my working tree all the files from the previous commit I was using, and put in place the files from the commit I'm switching to.*

  We need this because the *files* stored in every commit are frozen for all time, as a sort of permanent archive.  They're in a format that only Git can read, and nothing—not even Git itself—can overwrite.  To get any actual work done, we need the files in a format that every program can read and write.  These "working" files go into a "working area", which Git calls your *working tree*.
- Weirdly—or at least, it's weird if you are used to other earlier version control systems—at this time Git fills in an *extra copy* of each file, into what Git calls its *index* or *staging area*.  This thing is so important, and/or so badly named originally, that it actually has three names: the third one is the *cache*, but nowadays that name is mostly seen in flags like `git rm --cached`.

  The files in this extra in-between area—it sits *between* the frozen-for-all-time *current commit* and the working tree—are in the frozen *format*, pre-de-duplicated.  But unlike the files in a commit, they can be replaced wholesale.  This is what `git add` does.

When you run `git add` on a working tree file, Git reads the working tree file, compresses it into the internal format, and checks for duplicate content.  If the content is already stored anywhere in any commit in the repository, Git *re-uses* that file at this point.  If not, Git now has a prepared copy, ready to go into a new commit.

Either way, *before* you ran `git add`, the index held a copy of the file, pre-de-duplicated (hence just a reference to the same file that's in the commit), ready to be committed, and *after* you run `git add`, the index holds a copy of the file, pre-de-duplicated and ready to be committed.

In other words, *at all times*, the index holds *all* the files, ready to be committed.  This is your *proposed next snapshot*.  It starts out matching *this* snapshot, from the commit you've checked out.  As you run `git add`, you *update the proposed next snapshot*.

If you add an all-new file, Git compresses and checks for duplicate content as usual, and then writes a new name—this is where the forward-slash names come from—into the index, in a *new* index slot, instead of booting out the old prepared file.  So you can add all-new names.  You can also *remove* names *from* Git's index, using `git rm`.  In fact, since `git add` means *make the index copy match the working tree copy*, you can use `git add` to remove index copies!<sup>3</sup>

Ultimately, you run `git commit`, and at this time Git packages up *whatever is in its index right then* and that's the snapshot for the new commit.  Everything you do with your working tree is irrelevant *unless* you invoke `git add` or `git rm` or some similar Git command to make Git update its *index*.  At the time you *do* run `git commit`, Git takes a snapshot of the *staged* files, carefully arranged in its index / staging-area to make the prettiest picture you can construct.  So that's why you can call it the *staging area*.

---

<sup>3</sup>That is, suppose you check out a commit and it has a file named `path/to/file`.  You remove that file from your working tree, but not from Git's index.  Then you run `git add path/to/file`.  Git sees that there's a copy in its index, but that the working-tree copy is *gone*.  The `git add` command takes that to mean *remove the index copy to match*.  I find this weird, almost even spooky, myself and never use it on purpose; I prefer to run `git rm` instead.

---

#### A brief note on `git status`: use it often

The `git status` command:

- prints out the name of the current branch: `on branch main` or whatever;
- checks to see if the current branch has an *upstream*, and if so, will tell you about being ahead and/or behind (we won't cover this at all here); and then
- runs *two* `git diff` operations.

The `git diff` operation compares *two snapshots*.  You can use it on any two commits, and it will tell you what's *different* in those two commits.  But you can also use it on Git's index / staging-area, and on your working tree, and that's how `git status` tells you about *changes staged for commit* and *changes not staged for commit*.

When you compare two actual, existing commits—such as `G` and `H` in our diagrams above—Git extracts both snapshots and looks to see which files are exactly the same and hence de-duplicated, and which ones are different.  The exactly-the-same, de-duplicated files are *boring* and it doesn't mention those at all!  It only mentions the files that *don't* match.

When using a full `git diff`, Git plays a game of [Spot the Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference) for each doesn't-quite-match pair of files, and prints out a recipe for changing the old or left-hand-side version of the file into the new or right-hand-side version.  But you can ask it to just say *which files* and whether they're modified, or newly added or deleted.

The `git status` command uses this faster mode—the "just tell me which files are changed" mode—to compare the *current commit* and the *proposed new snapshot*.  For each file that's *changed* (or new or deleted), `git status` tells you that file's name and says that it is *staged for commit*.  It says nothing at all for files that match: those are boring!

Then, having printed out this list, `git status` does a second fast-mode diff to compare each *index* file to each *working tree* file.  Here, for each file that's *different*, `git status` lists them out again, this time putting them under the *not staged for commit* section.

Note that it's possible to "stage a change" and then change the same file again:

```
$ git switch main
$ echo more data >> existing-file
$ git add existing-file
$ echo another change >> existing-file
```

Now *all three copies* are different, so `git status` will list `existing-file` as both *staged for commit* **and** *not staged for commit*.  That's not how most people do most of their work most of the time, but if you get to advanced Git-ing, you can use `git add -p` to set this kind of thing up on purpose.

There's one last thing to touch on here, and that's the *untracked files*.  Again, I'm going to omit all of the important details, but there is a simple definition here for "untracked file": **An untracked file is a file that exists in your working tree *right now* but does not exist in Git's index *right now*.**  That's all it is.  Since you can change what's in Git's index, you can change whether some file is tracked or untracked—but remember, switching from one commit to another commit *also* changes what's in Git's index, by filling in Git's index from the commit to which you're switching.

This omits all kinds of special cases (see, e.g., [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452)), but it's plenty to start with.